# standalone - Can I specify the font size in the document?

Tags: standalone

I'd like to define the font size in a `standalone` document so that it is identical to the one in my "real" big document.

---

I have several `standalone`-documents. In those, I'd like to implement an option which makes the standalone-documents simply adhere to what is written in `font-config.tex` (see MWE)--which is currently empty.

(In my main document, I of course define the size as an option for the documentclass (scrreprt), but I am a bit clueless what to do here since standalone does not take `\KOMAoptions` obviously.)

**What should I write into `font-config.tex` so that it basically mimics whatever I define for my real document?**

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
12pt
]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\input{font-config}
%\KOMAoptions{fontsize=11pt}

\usepackage{
tikz,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\draw
(0,0) coordinate (A)
(1,1) coordinate (B)
;
\draw[thick] (A) rectangle (B) node[anchor=south west, align=left] {Words abc.\\Test.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`standalone` uses `article` as its 'base' class, but you can change this with the `class=<classname>` option. Hence, you could tell `standalone` to use a KOMA class with

```
\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
```

You can then use the `\KOMAoptions` directly in your `standalone` files, place it in the `font-config` file, or add the `fontsize` declaration to the class options directly.

Comment: But when I use this class, I no longer get the nice feature of `standalone` that my document is perfectly sized to my image.

Comment: @CarlSorensen Ehm, yes you do. Just try, `\documentclass[class=scrreprt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Only if the width of the image is less than the width of the page in the scrreport.  Try `\documentclass[class=scrreprt{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) grid (30,5); \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}`

Comment: @CarlSorensen Works perfectly fine here. I have no idea why you'd see different, so I'd suggest you ask a new question. Add `\listfiles` at the start of that code, and add the code and the `.log` file to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could also just set the fontsize:

`\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont`

First argument is the font size, second the baselineskip.

Comment: Although even _your_ reply is now 2 years old nearly to the day, I'd like to say thanks, yes that would be an alternative. To clarify, the reason behind my question is that the "standalone-file" would be in some sub-folder of the main latex document, thus the standalone-file should inherit some/all of the options which exist for the main document.