# Standalone vs IEEEtran

Tags: ieeetran, standalone

I have a figure to be used in an IEEE conference paper.
I have written the tikz code in separate file (fig.tex) as illustrated below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth]

\begin{axis}[ylabel={Label y},xlabel={Label x}]
...
\end{axis}
\end{document}
```

I compile this file and include the pdf in main.tex .
However, the fonts in the figure are not the same as the one in main.tex which has IEEEtran as the documentclass.

How do I get the font settings of IEEEtran in fig.tex ?

Comment: Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201487/standalone-can-i-specify-the-font-size-in-the-document/202341#202341

Comment: Or alternatively maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1475?

Comment: Looking at the source code, the fonts depend on which journal/option you use.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. that solution is perfect!