# Minion pro step by step installation

Tags: classicthesis

I write my thesis with `classic thesis` and I would like to use Minion pro fonts (regulars and italics) instead of Palatino. Therefore, I am about to buy those fonts. But, I understood that it was quite difficult to install it. Is there anyone who may help me to do it and guide me into a step-by-step installation ?

Comment: The first thing I still do nowadays when I am puzzled as to what is going on with some feature of LaTeX or which problem I can solve this or that way... is to Google. Thanks to the kraken, I learned LaTeX, basically. (And the companion.) So... did you google for it?

Comment: If you don't want to use the optical sizes (display, subhead, &c.), you don't have to buy them: they're supplied with Adobe Reader. What are your system and distribution?

Comment: @henry : Yes I did. I even tried to run a script retrieved from the net. But in vain. Bernard : I am working with Mac osx. I did not know for the adobe reader version. I am going to try it. But then, what do I have to do next ?

Comment: Easyest way: use LuaTeX. If for some reason you can't use LuaLaTeX, XeTeX does offer also OpenType support. If, for some reason, you need pdfTeX, then [here](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) you can see an explanation of how to do it.

Comment: @Bernard : I can use Minion Pro with Adobe Reader. But how can I do in order to use Minion Pro with my Latex editor ?

Comment: @domi Manuel just told you.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the way I should use Lualatex more than Latex alone : does it mean that I do not have to install any Minion Pro fonts ? That is the reason why I need some step-by-step guide : I do not understand anything at all (!).

Comment: @domi: I use Minion Pro very often with XeLaTeX and it works fine fir text. If you also have maths, it's more complex, because roughly you'll have to create first type 1 fonts from the Opentype fonts with the LCDF Type Tools, then a script to install them in your local TeX  directory. In your documents you'll have to load the `fontspec` package with option `no-math` and the `MinionPro` package with option `onlymath`.

Comment: @Bernard Could you please post your preamble regarding the fonts [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194928/best-practice-how-can-i-get-my-whole-document-including-math-to-only-use-fon)? It would help tremendously.

Comment: When I run the compilation that you indicate, I have the following error message : "The font « Adobe Garamond Pro » cannot be found." Therefore, my difficulty is to be able to know I have to do in order to put the fonts at the right place on my mac.

Comment: Do you think that I could run the following script [http://kieranhealy.org/blog/archives/2012/11/10/installing-minion-pro/]successfully if I had first bought the Minion Pro fonts ? The link seems not to work : paste it in your web browser instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you compile with XeLaTeX (perhaps also with LuaLaTeX, but I'm not sure), you can use *any*  font known to your system, so there's nothing to do, except use the exact Opentype names. Don't load `inputenc` (XeLaTeX supposes it's utf8-encoded (check the settings of your editor); don't load `fontenc` since you will use ordinary fonts (truetype or opentype).

You will have to load the dedicated font manager: `fontspec` and declare a main font with the `setmainfont` command. Likewise, you can declare `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont`. You can define the default font features you want, such as special ligatures, oldstyle numbers, tabular numbers, colour, &c. Actually, fontspec is an interface to opentype font features. For this, you have two main commands: `\setdefaultfontfeatures` and, if you want a font feature only for a short piece of text: `addfontfeatures`.

Of course, you'll find many more details in the documenation. And now for a small example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[marginratio={4:6, 5:7}, textwidth=131mm, noheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}% font selecting commands%
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers = {OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures = Rare, WordSpace = 1.1}%,2
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant = british]{english}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{verse}
\renewcommand*\vin[1][1]{\hspace*{#1\vgap}}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\title{\color{Tomato2}\bfseries\itshape\huge\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=2}The Great Panjandrum \\Himself}
\author{Samuel Foote}
\date{(1755)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{verse}

So she went into the garden

to cut a cabbage-leaf

to make an apple-pie;

and at the same time

 a great she-bear, coming down the street,

 pops its head into the shop.

What! no soap?

\vin So he died,

and she very imprudently married the Barber:

and there were present

\vin the Picninnies,

\vin[2] and the Joblillies,

\vin[3] and the Garyulies,

and the great Panjandrum himself,

with the little round button at top;

and they all fell to playing the game of catch-as-catch-can,

 till the gunpowder ran out at the heels of their boot
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You certainly like tomatoes.

Comment: @Manuel: It's the favourite fruit of the Picninnies ;o). More seriously, in coloured titles, I like best a red close to, but slightly different, from ‘basic red’ (RGB 1 0 0) and I prefer to use colour names rather than code.

Comment: OK. And is apacite package compatible with Xelatex ?

Comment: @domi: I don't know, as apacite is not installed  on my computer (I suse `biblatex`). However I don't see why it shouldn't work, and it's perfectly compatible with `bibalatex-apa`.